# Error during match when using union array

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the highest value in non contiguous range and print its address. I used data in Excel like in the picture below:

[image: Sample image]

The VBA code I used is:

```
Sub rngadd()

Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, newrng As Range
Dim dblmax As Double
Dim Xrng As Variant

Worksheets("sheet3").Activate
Set r1 = Range("A1:A5")
Set r2 = Range("A8:A12")
Set newrng = Union(r1, r2)
newrng.Select

dblmax = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(newrng)
Xrng = WorksheetFunction.Index(newrng, WorksheetFunction.Match(dblmax, newrng, 0)).address(False, False)
Worksheets(2).Range("D3").Value = dblmax
Worksheets(2).Range("E3").Value = Xrng

End Sub
```

I get an error as run-time error:

> '1004' unable to get the match property of worksheet function class"

but if I run the code just for the range `r1`, I get the expected result as in the image:

[image: Sample Image2]

So I found that I get the error because of using union, the match is unable to perform when there is a break in range(non contiguous range).

What should I do to get the desired result in non contiguous ranges like what I get in contiguous range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Find()` method of `Range` object:

```
Sub rngadd()

    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, newrng As Range
    Dim dblmax As Double
    Dim Xrng As Range

    Worksheets("sheet3").Activate
    Set r1 = Range("A1:A5")
    Set r2 = Range("A8:A12")
    Set newrng = Union(r1, r2)
    newrng.Select

    dblmax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(newrng)
    Set Xrng = newrng.Find(what:=dblmax, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    Worksheets(2).Range("D3").Value = dblmax
    Worksheets(2).Range("E3").Value = Xrng.Address

End Sub
```

But all that `Activate`/`Select` is bad practice,and you can also avoid `Union()` if you already know the ranges addresses in advance (as you currently do)

so please consider the following refactoring:

```
Sub rngadd()
    Dim newrng As Range
    Dim dblmax As Double

    Set newrng = Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A1:A5, A8:A12")

    dblmax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(newrng)

    With Worksheets(2)
        .Range("D3").Value = dblmax
        .Range("E3").Value = newrng.Find(what:=dblmax, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This one, I am just trying as an example. I will try to implement with large data. In that case i will not know the range. The thing I am trying to achieve is I have a range **starting from 0**, **[(1) 0 to Max]** value, then **[(2) Max to Min]** (which is contiguous) value and **[(3) Min to 0]**. So I will have 1 contiguous range and 2 Non contiguous range. That's why I am trying to use union to make the 2 Non contiguous range into one single contiguous range. Because I need like 2 Ranges which will look like **Max - Min** and **Min - Max**  for further processing. So any Ideas for that??

Comment: In case you didn’t know all single ranges in advance then you can still go with the first code of my answer, i.e.  “unioning” them into a “newrng” and then use Find() method on this latter. But you’re encouraged to refactor it in the fashion of the 2nd code

Answer (score 2):

Index and Match won't work on non-consecutive ranges.

You may loop through the cells to find the max value and it's corresponding cell address like below...

```
Sub rngadd()

Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, newrng As Range, cell As Range
Dim cellAddress As String
Dim maxVal As Long

Worksheets("sheet3").Activate
Set r1 = Range("A1:A5")
Set r2 = Range("A8:A12")
Set newrng = Union(r1, r2)

For Each cell In newrng
    If cell.Value > maxVal Then
        maxVal = cell.Value
        cellAddress = cell.Address(0, 0)
    End If
Next cell

Worksheets(2).Range("D3").Value = maxVal
Worksheets(2).Range("E3").Value = cellAddress

End Sub
```

Comment: That's true if the max value is figured out at the first place before going into the loop.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now how you changed the method.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't been Into loops in vba yet. I will try to understand it.